# Is there a MySQL client on OSX that has great useability?

Tags: mysql, macos

I'm looking for a MySQL client on OSX with a mac design philosophy. I've been using mac programs for too long and can't really go back to windows designed programs. I'm looking for a program that has a sleek UI and great convenience for common tasks. (For example, ss there a client that allows you to delete a row by selecting it after a select query?)

I've already read the other two SO threads, nothing there.

Price does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Querious is really awesome.](http://www.araelium.com/querious/)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) yet?

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to web apps, there is [SQLBuddy](http://sqlbuddy.com), which is all slick and AJAX-y.

Answer (score 0):

You may like [SQLPro for MySQL](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sqlpro-for-mysql-gui-ui-database/id899174769?ls=1&mt=12).

The app has a few neat features such as:

- Auto-completion and syntax highlighting.
- Tabbed based interface.
- Query primary key detection and the ability to edit results inline.
- Support for executing multiple queries at once.
- Quick access to tables, columns and more.
- Use one of the pre-built themes, or customize your own.
- Exporting options to CSV, JSON and XML.
- Importing from CSV, JSON or XML.

There is a seven day trial available [via the website](http://mysqlui.com).

Disclaimer: I'm the developer. Or if you pop me an email, I can send a free promo code.

Also, in direct response to

> (For example, is there a client that allows you to delete a row by selecting it after a select query?)

SQLPro for MySQL will detect your table and primary keys from an executed query. As long as all the primary keys are available you can edit, delete or insert directly from a result set.